# How to run Flask on Public IP of EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have used Flask in Python to create a simple web application. I have also created a Windows Amazon EC2 instance. What I would like to do, is be able to host the web application on the Public IP address associated with the EC2 instance, so that the web application can be accessed from anywhere on the Internet. In order to achieve this, I have added the Public IP of the EC2 instance to the `host` parameter inside `app.run()`. Thus, my Python code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def home():
  return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host = "5.13.*.*")
```

However, when I run this code inside of the virtual machine I get this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Does anybody know how I could fix this? Basically what I would like to do is to have my Flask server be accessed remotely from any network, and not just my localhost, but I don't know if I'm going about it the wrong way. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend removing `amazon-web-services` and `amazon-ec2` tags as this has nothing to do with those layers

Comment: Typically your public ip is not visible *on the host*; it's a forwarding configuration. Just configure your application to bind to all addresses (`0.0.0.0`) and things should work (provided your security group/firewall configuration is correct).

Comment: @larsks Thank you. I have tried this, but I still cannot connect to it. What should my security group be like for it to work?

Comment: What are your current security group rules? What port is the app running on? I think Flask defaults to port `5000`. You may also need to open the port in the Windows firewall.

Comment: @Mark B I currently have two rules. One is of type RDP on port 3389 and the other is of type HTTP on port 80. The "Source" option is set to 0.0.0.0/0 for both.

Comment: Well if Flask isn't configured to run on port `80` then that `HTTP` rule is not going to work. So I ask again, what port is it running on?

Comment: @Mark B The default port if 5000, yes. Should I specify a port in the parameters?

Comment: It sounds like you either need to open port `5000` in the security group, or change the port Flask is using.

Comment: @Mark B Thank you, I will try doing that.